# React long press item and pass on event of that item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, events, react-hooks

I am working on a note-taking Ionic/React project and I'm trying to make items in a list selectable when you long press them. As in, long pressing an item toggles selection mode, where you can then tap to select any other items you want.

However, I am not sure how to detect which item was long pressed, because the current long press library I use (to my knowledge) doesn't support event passing. It just detects when SOME item was long pressed, but doesn't allow that event (e) to be used as a reference point.

The current library I'm using is React-use, specifically: [This hook](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLongPress.md)

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a separate component for the list-items. In that component you can then use the hook to capture the long press for each item individually and execute a function passed via props (`onLongPress` for example), which the parent component (the list) would pass to the items.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be good to use `onMouseDown` or `onClick` event to store the currently selected item, and if the `long press` event is detected, you can add the currently selected item to the selected items array, and you can set selection mode to true.
From the next click, you can add those all to the selected items array.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. However, I am unable to do it this way because the useLongPress hook already uses the onMouseDown event, so I am getting errors.

Comment: Is it getting onClick event too?

Comment: It isn't, but the onClick event would never execute because the long press detection would kick in first. I love your idea but with this hook it seems I might have to go with the way @leodriesch described, which I'm looking into now.